# Determinants & Invariance of Coordinates?

Tags: linear-algebra

In relativity one has to preserve the identity $(ct)^2 - x^2 = (ct')^2 - (x')^2$ under a coordinate transformation. I think I've got my finger on a nice way to prove this for hyperbolic rotations without doing the computations but have run into trouble so first I'd like to examine why a trigonometric rotation matrix won't do the job, & in doing so I run into mathematical issue on how the determinant relates to the norm.

A rotation matrix is the matrix representation of an an orthogonal transformation & orthogonal transformations both satisfy both $\det{T} = 1$ & $<T(\vec{v}),T(\vec{w})> = <\vec{v},\vec{w}>$, where $<.>$ in this case is the Minkowski inner product $v^1w^1 - v^2w^2$. Using the rotation matrix

$$[T] = \left[ \begin{matrix}  \cos(\phi) & - \sin(\phi) \\ \sin(\phi) & \cos(\phi) \end{matrix} \right]$$

one notes $\det(T) = \cos^2(\phi) + \sin^2(\phi) = 1$.

Is there a way to use this simple information to show such a transformation will preserve $(ct)^2 + x^2 = (ct')^2 + (x')^2$ & not $(ct)^2 - x^2 = (ct')^2 - (x')^2$?

In other words, rather than writing out $<T(ct,x),T(ct,x)>$ to show it's not equal to $<(ct,x),(ct,x)>$ under the Minkowski inner product for trigonometric rotations (or to write it out to show they are equal in the hyperbolic case) is there a way to use the fact that the determinant is * + * = 1 to show this, or even some nice thing I'm missing that allows one to do this?

I ask because when you do things in terms of hyperbolic matrices you get $\det(T) =  \cosh^2(\phi) - \sinh^2(\phi) = 1$ which is of the form * - * = 1 & it seems to me that because you're determinant gave the form * - * = 1 which the inner product takes it hints at a relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The determinant of a linear operator is a number; it doesn't have any information about whether the expression that evaluated to that number had a plus or a minus sign in it.  There is an inherent loss of information involved.  I think you should remember that just because a linear operator has a determinant that is $\pm 1$ doesn't mean that it is orthogonal with respect to the space you're in.  For instance, I could have a map that takes the unit square to a rectangle with the same area and orientation.  Such a map would have unit determinant but it wouldn't be orthogonal.

In Minkowski or Euclidean space, there is still one reliable rule to determine if a linear operator is orthogonal: check that the rows or columns of the corresponding matrix are orthonormal unit vectors with respect to the space's metric.  A trig rotation matrix is orthogonal in Euclidean space yet *not* orthogonal in Minkowski space.

Comment: Thanks, I should have remembered this but got distracted by the determinant since I use $\cosh^2(\phi) - \sinh^2(\phi) = 1 = \det(T)$ to remember the form of the hyperbolic matrix!

Comment: The bottom of page 5 of this pdf: http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic1114187.files/Lorentz%20Transformations.pdf seems to suggest that there is something more to my original question! I don't know what that is yet but it's interesting...